# Sending SQL Server query as CSV via e-mail

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Currently I'm using SSIS w/ a hacky solution to get around it not supporting auth on SMTP servers.

Is there a better way I can save a query to a CSV file, then mail it as an attachment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use database mail to send the email as that supports attachments and auth on SMTP.